# Admin not loading right

Tags: admin

First time user. Just installed on InMotion Hosting VPS. Front displays OK, bu the admin area is a mess (see attached) and I can't go anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Front end now isn't loading right, either.

Comment: Something's preventing the style sheets from loading.

Comment: Yes, but what? I don't even know where to start. Been working with Joomla! for years. This is my first Magento and I can't get passed install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the permissions thing, the best you can do is to check source code & see what URLs are being loaded in the head. A theme misconfiguration could lead to loading files which don't exist

Comment: Yep, go into back end, view code source for the page, look in the `<head>` for the CSS links, click on them and see if they load. They either don't have the right permissions (403) or didn't get installed (404). The backend theme is a default theme that is independent of the public site.

Answer (score 0):

Check if magento has access to the media/ folder.
This problem happens when Apache has no permissions to write into the media folder.

You should also check the owner rights of the media folder:

```
chown -R <apache_user> media
chmod -R o+w media
```

Also try the manual to see which permissions needed:
[Magento 1 File Permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html)